# Bukkit API How to set material data to an itemstack

Tags: java, bukkit

I am using Bukkit API 1.8.3

I am trying to compare `ItemStacks` based on their `Material` and `MaterialData`, to do this I must make the `ItemStacks` exactly the same and then change the Material and `MaterialData` of one `ItemStack`.

I know how to change the material using `setType()` but I do not know how to set a `MaterialData`. The method for this is `setData(MaterialData)` However, how do you have `MaterialData` as a variable?

I searched on Google, Stackoverflow, Spigot forums and bukkit forums and could not find an answer.

How can I set `MaterialData` to an `ItemStack`?

NOTE: I cannot *try* this with no hint or idea on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you can use getType() on your Itemstack, to get the Material and call getData() afterwards to get the MaterialData.

Comment: I was trying to go for `setData()`, but I found an alternative with your way by having a temp ItemStack with the data and setting that to the other itemstack.